# AirDrop slow, taking 10+seconds to initiate - iOS & iPadOS 16.2 and earlier

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Has anyone found a fix for this? It feels really spilling sitting there when trying to send a picture to my wife, and it just says waiting.

Both are iPhone 13 Pros.

I have restarted and force restarted both devices, and tried going into airplane mode first.

Comment: Do you have a VPN set up and running on the iPhones?

Comment: I do, but not enabled at the time.